# Gauntlet mode in Desktop Dungeons

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

I won with a human fighter (pretty easy combo, after all) and unlocked the all new Gauntlet mode.

> Play through increasingly difficult dungeon runs in a quest for honour, glory and bragging rights among your friends! Each successive Gauntlet victory will make **all future runs** slightly more difficult. What's your lifetime maximum going to be?

What does "all future runs" mean? Does it make the game *globally* harder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game does not become globally harder, only future runs of the Gauntlet itself become harder. The idea is that advancing in the Gauntlet requires you to gather up more skill by playing the other challenges, so the Gauntlet itself does not change those challenges.